# How do you allow access to your website for people in China?

Tags: server, country-specific, firewall

My website recently got blocked by the Chinese government. I considered moving the server out of China to somewhere like Singapore where it would not lengthen the latency too much, but still do the job.

Are there better ways to bypass the block on my website?

Comment: Sorry if this question offends you, but does your website contain content that may be violating any kind of governmental law? What is it about?

Comment: It is a website for educational purposes, provides opportunity for chinese student to study abroad

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience get in touch with a web dev there.

They can find out why you were blocked.

I know devs from China usually submit to the govt there before going live.

And they will send you back their approved version they edited.

Not a good choice if you wanna have freedom of speech etc...

Comment: I need a more technical solution hopefully this is not breaking the law here in us.

Comment: The Govt. in China controls the internet. They control the routers, the cables, EVERYTHING! Sadly it doesn't matter what you do tech wise. They need to approve you. Unlike here where we have freedom and can follow simple guidelines.

Comment: So far I am just looking at what I can do on my part. I know there are softwares people can download to bypass the block.

Comment: Yeah people look up illegal sites in the US as well all the time. But let them do that. Don't put your self in jeopardy. All you can do is create a solid website. How they get to it is not your problem. Aside from tech issues of course.

Comment: I have the same issue (educational content website) Is there a place where i can submit my site for review (similar to what a chines developer would do)?